# How to Bind and LIKE in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, prepared-statement, sql-like

I am trying to make a query where there is a bind and a LIKE.
The query itself if I change the where for 1 works, so it is a problem of the bind and query.

Can someone give me a hand with that:

```
$vendor = $this->fetchAll(
            $this->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from('vendor', array('vendor_id'))
                ->join('user', 'vendor_user_id = user_id', array('user_id','user_name'))
                ->where("user_name LIKE (':keyword%')")
                ->limit(10)
                ->bind(array(
                    'keyword' => $keyword,
                ))
        );
```

I am trying to get something like this for the keyword "Cake"

```
.
.
.
WHERE user_name LIKE ('Cake%')
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the percent `%` is not escaped. So you can use it inside your `bind` function or directly with `where`

```
$vendor = $this->fetchAll(
            $this->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from('vendor', array('vendor_id'))
                ->join('user', 'vendor_user_id = user_id', array('user_id','user_name'))
                ->where("user_name LIKE (':keyword')")
                ->limit(10)
                ->bind(array(
                    'keyword' => $keyword . '%',
                ))
        );
```

Or without using bind

```
->where('user_name LIKE ?', $keyword.'%');
```